# finduser query returning nil Parse and swift

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to find which user commented on the blog post. but it always returns nil and total objects 0, i'm not sure what am i doing wrong. This is my code to get the user's username

```
var finduser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
finduser.whereKey("ObjectId", equalTo: commentclass.objectForKey("byuser").objectId)
finduser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let aobjects = objects {
           let puser = (aobjects as NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser
            cell.userName.text = puser?.username
            println(puser) // returns nil
            println(aobjects.count) // returns 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be **o**bjectId and not **O**bjectId, also make sure there is no ACL set for the user object that might prohibit the requesting user from seeing this object.

Comment: thanks i figured it out, i dont know why i had capital O in my mind